# z-index is not functioning

Tags: css, z-index

I wanted to add class `.tag` on my image which is in the class `.product-img`. So i use the method of z-index. I style the z-index in my image tag but the `.tag`  is not overlapped on my `.product-img`. As shown in the image shown below.  I do not know what mistake i did here. Any help will be appreciated thanks!

[image: the output]

```
    <?php 
     if ($preorder_stock == 0){
      echo" <img id='productimg' class='product-img'  loading='lazy' src='../images/product-main/".$row['product_photo']."' > 

      <div id='circle'><p style='font-size:8px; padding-top:30%; text-align:center; ''>Pre Order</br> NOW</p> </div>
          
      " ;
     }else{
       echo" <img style='z-index:-1;' id='productimg' class='product-img'  loading='lazy' src='../images/product-main/".$row['product_photo']."' >
       <div class='tag' style='padding-top:20px;'>
             <div id='circle'><p  style='font-size:8px; padding-top:30%; text-align:center; ''>Pre Order</br> NOW</p> </div>
             </div>

       " ;

     }?>
```

Comment: `z-index` doesn't change the flow, it doesn't make elements overlap.  If elements overlap, it controls which one is on top.

Comment: So you need to use appropriate `position` style to make them overlap.

Comment: @Barmar but my `.tag` does not show on top of the `.product-img` even if i set it to `z-index:-1px`

Comment: @Barmar does it means i cannot use `z-index` to make this work?

Comment: That's what I said. Setting z-index doesn't make them overlap, because they're not at the same position.

Comment: It means you have to use z-index along with positioning to make them be at the same place.

Comment: Put them both in the same DIV. Use `position:relative` to make them overlap, and `z-index` to specify which is on top.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094143/absolute-position-for-dynamic-content for something similar.

Comment: Can you get rid of the PHP and just post sample HTML in the question. Put it in an executable stack snippet.